# Multiplying matrices with a vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, dimension

I am trying to multiply 2 matrices in Matlab, but they don't have the same dimension. In fact, my multiplication isn't quite the standard matrix multiplication.
I have a *31*-by-*1* matrix (or vector), and a *31*-by-*512*-by-*512* matrix.
I would like to take the 1st element of my vector and multiply the 1st *512*-by-*512* slice with it and so on, resulting in a new *31*-by-*512*-by-*512* array.
But I don't want to use for loops for performance issues.

Answer (score 2):

This is the straightforward use-case of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html):

```
bsxfun(@times, v, M)
```

Or you might have to `permute` you vector, `v`, so that its *singelton* dimension is orthogonal the direction you want to expand over (in your case it's actually along dimension one *and* two), i.e. turn `v` into a *31*-by-*1*-by-*1* (although I'm not certain if this is necessary, try it if you get errors) as in your case you will be *expanding* along the third dimension:

```
bsxfun(@times, permute(v,[1,3,2]), M)
```

Note that another common way to do this is using `repmat` and `.*` but `bsxfun` is more efficient.